# Generate random characters against specific loop condition

Tags: python, string, function, while-loop

I want to continue generating a single character at random as long as the loop condition is not met. I was hoping my code below will work but it doesn't:

```
import string
import random

def random_characters(number):
    i = 0
    new_string = ''

    while (i < number) :
        new_string = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
        i = i + 1
        return new_string


random_characters(3)
```

When i run this code nothing happens and I don't get any feedback about any error. I may be using `return new_string` in a wrong way but I am unable to figure it out even if that is what I'm missing.

Comment: This may help: [What does `return` do? Nothing is ever returned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066925/what-does-return-do-nothing-is-ever-returned) and BTW your `return` statement is not indented properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your `return` is inside the loop, so you don't ever loop several times. Change it to

```
def random_characters(number):
    i = 0
    new_string = ''

    while (i < number) :
        new_string = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
        i = i + 1
    return new_string # <<< Dedent

random_characters(3)
#>>> 'c'
```

Then you need to actually build `new_string`, not just set it each time. Build a `list` and then `"".join` it:

```
def random_characters(number):
    i = 0
    letters = [] # Place to put the letters

    while (i < number) :
        letters.append(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)) # <<< Add the letter
        i = i + 1
    return "".join(letters) # <<< Join the letters into one string

random_characters(3)
#>>> 'lgp'
```

Then you should use `for i in range(number)` instead of the `while` loop:

```
def random_characters(number):
    letters = []

    for i in range(number): # <<< Deals with i for you.
        letters.append(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase))

    return "".join(letters)

random_characters(3)
#>>> 'xay'
```

And you can use a shortened version with a list comprehension:

```
def random_characters(number):
    # MAGIC!
    letters = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(number)]

    return "".join(letters) # <<< Join the letters into one string

random_characters(3)
#>>> 'yby'
```

---

If you're wanting to run this, you have several choices. Either you can run this in the **interactive** interpreter:

```
%~> python -i random_characters.py
>>> random_characters(3)
'zgp'
```

or you can tell it to `print` the result inside the file:

```
print(random_characters(3))  # Python 3
print random_characters(3)   # Python 2
```

Comment: Just a note: there's a convention (or, well, it's commonplace) to use `_` as a loop variable if you're not going to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons:

- You discard the characters you create (by reassigning to the same name)
- You only return the first character anyway (by returning inside the loop)

Instead, consider doing:

```
import string
import random

def random_characters(number):
    i = 0
    random_chars = []

    while (i < number) :
        random_chars.append(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase))  # Store the char you generate
        i = i + 1

    return ''.join(random_chars)  # Return once you have all the characters
```

Of course, that's not the most Pythonic way there is to do this. Here's a way that doesn't loop over an artificial condition:

```
def random_characters(number):
    return "".join((random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in xrange(number)))
```

Note: this is called a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

Comment: This still didn't answer: **When I run this code nothing happens**

Comment: @hcwhsa You'll probably want to add a `print` statement in front of `random_characters(3)` if you want some output to appear: `print random_characters(3)`. Right now, you're generating the random string and throwing it away.

Comment: That's what OP was asking for, and you didn't mention anything related to that in your answer. Even if they use your code they'll get no output.

Comment: @hcwhsa Sure, and? I'm sorry to break that to you, but the OP's code wasn't going to work anyway. Now you got two fixes when you only asked for one.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco very true. The return statement was inside the loop and I had to bring it outside. Again true, I was generating random numbers and throwing them away hence I needed a 'print' statement to make sure that something actually *happens*. thanks